# Are Facades in EJB the same thing as service in a spring-based web application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, architecture, ejb

I've participated in several projects of Spring-based web-application - and have written a quantity myself. Usually we have (roughly speaking) following folders to divide our classes by categories like `dao`, `models`, `web` (for controllers if we use Spring MVC or backing beans for JSF for example) and also **service** - here we keep what we think is business-logic (even when sometimes classes here simply forward methods to dao).

Now I am faced with development of EJB application - I've learnt that I will have some `web` and `model` classes anyway. Also I may use dedicated `dao` layer or may put data access into `facades` (I prefer dedicated folder though it increases verbosity).

But I do not understand clearly whether **facades** are exactly the place to put business-logic in it, or I should add `services` folder for it and use `facades` more like `dao` (eliminating `dao` itself).

I also would be glad for short and comprehensive compilation of hints on EJB application architecture.

Comment: Isn't *facade* a pattern where you offer a higher level API to users that itself again uses services that more complex or "internal"?

Comment: yes, it is, though it is a question to me whether in architecture of EJB application `facade` means only pattern or the structural element of application (often implemented in the way of the same pattern) - I would be glad if anyone explain this to me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a similar setup with EJB as you have done with Spring. You have your web package (MVC stuff), then your service layer which contains most business logic and then DAO layer which contains basic CRUD operations and some database queries.

In this scenario you can test the possibly complex business logic in the session beans with fast unit tests that don't need database and you can mock the DAO access here. Then you can have relatively simple tests for your DAO layer, so the number of tests requiring database (ie. that are consirably slower) is smaller.

Normally I would call `facade` a set of session beans that offer simple methods for operating the system via for example Web services. These beans would use the normal service layer beans. With just a web layer and no integration layers I don't see a reason to create an extra `facade` layer.

Comment: Thanks! I like the way you propose and your explanations. Perhaps I'll accept it if there would be no other ideas :)

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with your project.